# Get chat_id from the chat which contains specifc users

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, database-design

DB-Design:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynByR.png]

I would like to determine the `chat_id`, to which 2 certain users belong. The `user_id` is known. For example, user 25 and user 28 belong to the `chat_id 1`. These belong also to the group chat with the `chat_id 2`. However, the `chat_id` should be determined which only these two users have. What SQL query can I use? I tried it as follows:

```
[SELECT chat_id FROM `chat_partners` WHERE private=1 AND (F_user_id=100 OR F_user_id=50) GROUP BY chat_id HAVING count(*)=2;][1]
```

There, however, I was also given the `chat_id 1` when I have two non-existent `user_id`'s specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt does not look far off, but the check for each user needs to happen in the `HAVING` clause, not the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT chat_id
FROM chat_partners
WHERE private = 1
GROUP BY chat_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN F_user_id = 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN F_user_id = 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

This will return every `chat_id` having both users 25 and 28.  However, other users may also be present.  If you want only chats exclusively containing these two users (e.g. a private chat), then you can add an additional term to your `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN F_user_id <> 25 AND F_user_id <> 28 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want groups that have those two users *and* others, then an easy way is:

```
SELECT chat_id
FROM chat_partners
WHERE private = 1 AND
      F_user_id IN (25, 28)
GROUP BY chat_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;  -- If there can be duplicates, then use `COUNT(DISTINCT F_user_id)`;
```

If you want chats with *exactly* those users and no others:

```
SELECT chat_id
FROM chat_partners
WHERE private = 1
GROUP BY chat_id
HAVING SUM(F_user_id = 25) > 0 AND SUM(F_user_id = 28) > 0;
```